# Shopify orders array issue

Tags: php, arrays, shopify

I have these two arrays

```
  $order2 = array('line_items' => array(
    array('title' => 'Shipping',
    'price' => '10',
    'quantity' => '2',
  )
));

  $order3 =array('title' => 'Handling',
    'price' => '5',
    'quantity' => '1',
  );
```

I've used array_merge and array_push in this instance but both don't give me my desired output. I'm trying to get it to show like this.

```
array('line_items' => array(
    array('title' => 'Shipping',
    'price' => '10',
    'quantity' => '2',
      ),
    array('title' => 'Handling',
    'price' => '5',
      'quantity' => '1',
      )
    ));
```

The output i get is

```
Array ( [line_items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => Shipping [price] => 10 [quantity] => 2 ) ) [title] => Handling [price] => 5 [quantity] => 1 )
```

How can i achieve my desired output so i can use this as a shopify order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any functions to do that, just a simple array assignment on top of the existing one:

```
$order2['line_items'][] = $order3;
```

Comment: Hole-in-one! :P

Comment: I feel stupid af xD. Thank you for this answer. I will mark it as the answer in 1 minute